# Vue 3 clean up props before use

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way to clean up props in Vue 3 before they are used?

I'm currently struggling with the following problem:
My props can be either objects or stringified JSONs of said objects. The app I'm working on solved this by overwriting the pros in the created method.

This of course is not a good solution and my linter is complaining about it, so I'd like to fix it. I have no control over the components that use the component I'm working on, so I can't do it in the parent before my component is used.

I saw that the default option can use a method that can provide a rawData parameter, so thought I might do something like this:

```
defineProps({ 
  data: {
    type: [Object, String],
    default: ((rawData) => {
      if(typeof rawData === 'string') {
        return JSON.parse(rawData);
      }
      return rawData;
    }
  }
});
```

But it seems like that doesn't work as I hoped. I assume that the default is only used, when no data is provided, which is to be expected. Is there a way to do something like this every time, even when data is provided?

My current solution would be to put the props in refs and then fix those, but since I don't need the values to be reactive that seems a bit over the top.

Comment: Can't you just use computed value which is descringified prop? Nevermind, you do that already

Comment: I think no, props are immutable by definition

Comment: Do you use Script Setup or Options?

Comment: This is the case for a computed. Not necessarily as complex as the answer shows if it's a single prop

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following function to unjson all props:

```
import { computed, toRefs, Ref } from 'vue'

export function unjsonProps<T extends object>(props: T): { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], string> } {
  const refs = toRefs(props);
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries<Ref>(refs)
      .map(([k, r]) => [k, computed(() => typeof r.value === 'string' ? JSON.parse(r.value) : r.value)])
  ) as any
}
```

```
const props = defineProps(...)
const properProps = unjsonProps(props) // the same object with parsed strings
```

---

```
// unjsonProps.js
import { computed, toRefs } from 'vue';
export function unjsonProps(props) {
    const refs = toRefs(props);
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(refs)
        .map(([k, r]) => [k, computed(() => typeof r.value === 'string' ? JSON.parse(r.value) : r.value)]));
}
// unjsonProps.d.ts
export declare function unjsonProps<T extends object>(props: T): {
    [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], string>;
};
```